# How to keep two blocks containing item lists in the same position after overlay

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, block

I've been trying to use the overprint and overlayarea environments to keep 2 blocks with lists inside in the same position The items of the lists should also have overlays. For some reason, overprint neither overlayarea seem to work. Here is the code I'm using.

Is there a way to keep overlaid blocks with overlaid item lists inside in the same position?

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 

\author{Lorem ipsum}
\title{Lorem ipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \usetheme[hideallsubsections,left,width=2cm]{Marburg}

\usecolortheme{rose}
 \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=structure,fg=white}

\logo{ \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Logo.png}}

  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
      \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
      \insertlogo

      \vspace{\baselineskip}
      \color{white}{\insertshorttitle[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}

\insertshortauthor[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks] \vspace{\baselineskip}

\insertverticalnavigation{2cm}

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

\insertframenumber

  }


\begin{document}


\section{Lorem Ipsum}


\begin{frame}
\begin{overprint}[\textwidth]



\onslide<1-4> {
 \begin{block}{\hfill erga}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item 123
   \item 1234.
   \item 12455.
   \item LOrep ipsum.
 }
  \end{itemize}

 \end{block}

 \onslide<5-7>{

 \begin{block}{\hfill E3}


  \begin{itemize}
   \item aergaergaerg
   \item Genaerg.
   \item tahthhaethetros.
   \item aehathahtarhat. 
  \end{itemize}

 \end{block}
}

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you need. I switched to `overlayarea` and used `\only` instead of `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 

\author{Lorem ipsum}
\title{Lorem ipsum}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme[hideallsubsections,left,width=2cm]{Marburg}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=structure,fg=white}

%\logo{ \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{Logo.png}}

  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
      \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
      \insertlogo

      \vspace{\baselineskip}
      \color{white}{\insertshorttitle[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks]}

\insertshortauthor[width={2cm},center,respectlinebreaks] \vspace{\baselineskip}

\insertverticalnavigation{2cm}

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

\insertframenumber
}


\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{5cm}
\only<1-4>{%
 \begin{block}{\hfill\strut erga}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \item 123
   \item 1234.
   \item 12455.
   \item Lorep ipsum.
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
}
 \only<5-8>{%
 \setcounter{beamerpauses}{5}
 \begin{block}{\hfill\strut  E3}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \item aergaergaerg
   \item Genaerg.
   \item tahthhaethetros.
   \item aehathahtarhat. 
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gonzalo, but this way I can't make overlays for the items.

Comment: @Charlie Then perhaps I misunderstood the question. How exactly are you trying to display the items?. Can you please describe in detail?

Comment: So, both blocks should have overlays, and within the blocks the items of the lists should also have overlays (say \item<1> afaef \item<2>egaerg and so on).

In other words, the first slide should show the first block with the first list item, then the second item and so on, then the second block with the first list item should be shown and then the second list item and so on. Both blocks should be in the same position. Is that possible?

Comment: @Charlie Sure. Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you are trying to achieve?